# Anyone know where I can find this book

Tags: agada-stories-legends

[image]

Anyone know where I can find this book online either to buy or if it’s a pdf online or something? It’s a very skinny brown book

Comment: Did you check for publisher/contact information inside the cover and try to get in touch with them?

Comment: Did you try seforim stores in Brooklyn?

Comment: @magicker72 it just had an email which apparently doesn’t exist

Comment: @mbloch not yet, was hoping to find it online if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try Eichler's of Boro Park as print editions of this sefer are [available for ordering online](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/chidushei-agados/56910) (*I know of no PDF editions*).

I got to this in a roundabout way - good thing for worldcat.org!
I searched there for some [key words from your title](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=%22%D7%9C%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F%22).
This led me to [a listing](https://www.worldcat.org/title/1345009453) which informed me that the publisher was מרדכי צבי געטץ.

After some additional Google searches on that name, it turns out that this is none other that Mordy Getz the owner of Eichler's Judaica, so I searched for לרבינו משה מלובלין on their web site.

Comment: Thanks so much!